# Unit testing a function with a timestamp

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I have an object function to send **news** to an **API**:

```
class Manager
{
    public function __construct(GuzzleHttp\Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }


    public function uploadNews($title, $text, $timestamp = null)
    {
        // DEFAULT FOR PUBLISH TIMESTAMP IS SET IF VALUE IS NULL
        $timestamp = $timestamp ?? time();

        $requestBody = [
            'header' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
            ],
            'timeout' => 300,
            'body' => [
                'title' => $title,
                'text' => $text,
                'publish_date' => $timestamp,
            ]
        ];

        return $this->client->request('POST', 'http://api/endpoint', $requestBody);
    }
}
```

How do I write a PHPUnit unit test to test the final `$request` passed to the client's `request()` function is of the expected format, when the `$timestamp` is not set (the API expects a timestamp)? I've written a unit test. But is not ideal, since there could be a difference in the tow timestamps.

```
class ManagerTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testCanUploadNewsWithoutTimestamp()
    {
        $expectedRequestBody = [
            'header' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
            ],
            'timeout' => 300,
            'body' => [
                'title' => 'News title',
                'text' => 'News article sample text.',
                'publish_date' => time(),
            ]
        ];

        $guzzleMock = $this->createMock(GuzzleHttp\Client::class);
        $guzzleMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('request')
            ->with(
                'POST',
                'http://api/endpoint',
                $expectedRequestBody
            );

        (new Manager($guzzleMock))->uploadNews(
            'News title',
            'News article sample text.'
        );
    }
}
```

This is my current test result:

```
Parameter 2 for invocation GuzzleHttp\Client::request('POST', 'http://api/endpoint', Array (...)) does not match expected value.
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
     'body' => Array (
         'title' => 'News title'
         'text' => 'News article sample text.'
-        'publish_date' => 1574550178
+        'publish_date' => 1574550179
     )
 )
```

**Please note that the only thing I need to make sure is that the timestamp is passed with request. The value of the timestamp doesn't matter.**

PS: I'm really new to Test Driven Development, so the answer might be obvious and I might still not know it.

Comment: Seems to me that your method allows you to pass a known timestamp-as it should-so why not use it?  The only reason for not passing a value in would be to prove that it can default to time(), but that introduces uncertainty. Is there another reason for not passing a known value?

Comment: try mocking the `time()` function like described in [this blog](https://ttmm.io/php/mocking-time-in-unit-tests/)

Comment: @TimMorton I'm trying to learn Test driven development. So, the test is actually written first and it should be able to test "testCanUploadNewsWithoutTimestamp", in which case the timestamp should be added to the request anyway since the API expects it. The only thing I need to make sure is that the timestamp is passed with request. The value of the timestamp doesn't matter.

Comment: @Matteo I checked the blog and tried that method too. But the issue here is that the assertion is being done with the `$expectedRequestBody ` array I generated and the `$requestBody` array being passed to the `$client->request()` method. So the timestamp in the argument array is not known to the test. PS: The value of the timestamp doesn't really matter. But for the sake of comparison, I'll need to provide one. That's where the issue is happening.

Comment: This is always tricky and will never give you a clean solution. Something that I like to do when I'm dealing with situations like this is simply make a new class for them. So in your case I would make something like a `TimestampRetriever` class that has a function that returns `time()`. You can quite easily test this class in a standalone test and in your current test you can mock it and have full control over the timestamp you will get back. Not very pretty, but it works.